# Redirect to the last visited page

Tags: redirect

We are thinking to redirect users, when visiting our website, to the their last visited page. The flow will be:

1. User is in a page of our site, let's name it Collection Page
2. User closes the website
3. User visits again the website by typing on the url the homepage
4. In that case redirect the user to the last visited page "Colletion Page" of his previous session

What do you think about it? Is it a good or bad UX?

Thank you

Comment: What user problem are you solving with a redirect to the last visited page?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is a user problem, but a product problem. On the website of my company we have 2 products, lets say X and Y products. At the homepage you can only see the product X. The only way to see the second product Y is on the navigation menu. So we would like to get users of product Y direct to this product, assuming of course that the last time they visited the website they exit the site from product Y

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to show product Y on the homepage as well? Other than in the navigation menu?

Comment: What is the user story / job story behind this idea? How it will help your users, or achieve your goals?

Answer (score 0):

An example of a good use case for directing user to the last page visited would be if your site was a discussion/forum type of site.

So let's say the user views a particular discussion thread, and that thread has many comments on it. The first time the user clicks on the thread it should take them to the original posts with comments under it sorted in chronological order.

But say the user only reads a few comments and exits the thread. If they decide to navigate back to the thread, it should take them to the last comment that they viewed.

Answer (score 0):

With more insight into this problem, we could certainly be more precise. To be honest, I am going to give you my perspective on this problem / challenge.

Firstly. You need to understand the user's needs and behavior. You may have a valid case if your users navigate to product X more often than product Y. However, in cases where product Y needs to be pushed more often, this approach may be ineffective.

I approach every project from the perspective of the user. This kind of approach would not go over well with me based on my experience and memory. Here's why. I would bookmark that page if I wish to be directed to it every time. There are already enough systematic features that allow you to do this. For example, browser prediction, autocomplete, bookmarks, last closed tab.

Refactoring the main navigation could provide a user with the ability to quickly get to a specific collection and do things there more often.

Tell us more about what you're thinking and we could figure something out.